# Get view from linked layout in Preference Category Android

Tags: android, layout, view, preference

I want to know how to get the views from a linked layout in preference activity.

```
<PreferenceCategory android:key="HEADER"
    android:layout="@layout/prefernce_top_layout"
    android:title="Application Settings" >
```

I want to get the views from "prefernce_top_layout.xml"...
Currently I am doing this but unable to get View..

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.
userProfilePic = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.profile_DP_settings);
```

Please Help! Thanks

Comment: I got it done by myself.. Anyone else want to know then get back to me..

Comment: Hi..i am facing a problem while getting the views inside the linked layout to the preference screen. Can you tell me how you achieved it ?

Comment: I have answered the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a separate UI and load it like this in onCreat method:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
setContentView(R.layout.prefernce_top_layout);
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_DP_settings"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/appicon"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fbUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profile_DP_settings"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_DP_settings"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout" />
```

Comment: Listview at end will point your preferences list items, rest of the views are extra and you can add what you want.

Comment: this will work for a single preference. For multiple preferences this won't work.